# What is the proper way to write C++ extension for asynchronous model in python web-frameworks?

Tags: python, c++, asynchronous, twisted, cython

I write C++ extension for using of it in twisted web-server, so It works not well with deferreds and callbacks and every time it's totally synchronous. It seems that the python's interpreter release GIL for every call of C++ extension's functionality. I use cython to write a bridge between C++ functions and Python. So the question is: What is the proper way of writing of C++ extensions for asynchronous web frameworks with non-blocking style?
Could It help to use "nogil" mode for cython extension?